# Uncaught TypeError: arr.filter is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have printed **arr** values in console they are like

```
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

but when this function gives an error i am not getting any values in **arr**

> Uncaught Type Error: arr.filter is not a function

I am new to java-script and i don't have any idea what's this error is

```
function filter(arr, criteria) {
   return arr.filter(function (obj) {
        return Object.keys(criteria).every(function (c) {
            return obj[c] == criteria[c];
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: is `**arr**` actually in your code or did you just try to highlight it?

Comment: @NullDev  yes i highlight it

Comment: The error states that the `.filter()` function doesn't apply to the type that is stored in `arr`.  `var x = [];x.filter(function() {})` confirms that `.filter` works on an *array*.  Therefore your `arr` variable is **not an array**.

Comment: Regardless of what you get in console, how do you generate `arr` that you pass into your filter function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the arr you are sending to the filter function is not an array, which is why the error is saying that arr.filter is not a function.

Just tried this and it works, so your function seems ok:

```
function filter(arr, criteria) {
   return arr.filter(function (obj) {
        return Object.keys(criteria).every(function (c) {
            return obj[c] == criteria[c];
        });
    });
}

const arr = [
  {
    name: "David",
    age: 54
  },
  {
    name: "Andrew",
    age: 32
  },
  {
    name: "Mike",
    age: 54 
  }
];
const myFilter = {"age": 54};
const result = filter(arr, myFilter);

console.log(result);
```